# Path helpers in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Foo that `:has_many` Bars. `GET Foo#index` shows all of the Bars. View looks like this:

```
<% @foos.each do |foo| %>
    <% foo.bars.each do |bar| %>
        <%= link_to 'Download', download_bar_path %>
        <%= link_to 'New', new_bar_path( :foo => foo.id ) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

There is a `def download` in Bars controller and a route:

```
resources :bars do
    member do
        get 'download'
    end
end
```

`rake routes` shows

```
download_bar GET    /bars/:id/download(.:format)     {:action=>"download", :controller=>"bars"}
```

and URL `/bars/1/download` really works, but the first link in the view (`download_bar_path`) doesn't. It says `No route matches {:action=>"download", :controller=>"bars"}`.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @foos.each do |foo| %>
  <% foo.bars.each do |bar| %>
    <%= link_to 'Download', [:download, bar] %>
    <%= link_to 'New', [:new, :bar] %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specified the bar to download, you need to add it by changing this line

```
<%= link_to 'Download', download_bar_path(bar) %>
```